# Funding from Advisor

Tags: funding

This semester, my advisor supports me financially from his NSF funding. So I was wondering if I can write this NSF funding in my resume in honors section?

Answer (score 3):

It’s not an “honor” to be funded by a normal NSF grant, or any other grant. It’s how you got funded, and is not something you can typically claim as an “award,” because it doesn’t represent you specifically. The only exception to this would be if you were somehow involved in the preparation of the grant.